# Pandas aggfunc sum based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm trying to sum data from multiple columns in my dataframe by pivoting the table and using aggfunc. My dataframe gives emission data for various regions.  I don't want to sum some rows so I make a selection of the rows that I want to sum. The output however is two rows for each column:

- one is named True and gives the sum of the rows that I defined (this is the column that I want)
- the other is named False and gives the sum of the remainder of the rows that I did not define (this one I would like to drop/omit)

The data is numeric regional data for multiple years so what I want to do is add data from some regions in order to get data for larger regions. The years are listed in columns.

The data looks something like this:

```
inp = [{'Scenario':'Baseline', 'Region':'CHINA', 'Variable':'Methane', 'Unit':'MtCO2eq', '1990':5,'1995':10,'2000':15},
   {'Scenario':'Baseline', 'Region':'INDIA', 'Variable':'Methane', 'Unit':'MtCO2eq', '1990':6,'1995':11,'2000':16},
   {'Scenario':'Baseline', 'Region':'INDONESIA', 'Variable':'Methane', 'Unit':'MtCO2eq', '1990':7,'1995':12,'2000':17},
   {'Scenario':'Baseline', 'Region':'KOREA', 'Variable':'Methane', 'Unit':'MtCO2eq', '1990':8,'1995':13,'2000':18},
   {'Scenario':'Baseline', 'Region':'JAPAN', 'Variable':'Methane', 'Unit':'MtCO2eq', '1990':9,'1995':14,'2000':19},
   {'Scenario':'Baseline', 'Region':'THAILAND', 'Variable':'Methane', 'Unit':'MtCO2eq', '1990':10,'1995':15,'2000':20},
   {'Scenario':'Baseline', 'Region':'RUSSIA', 'Variable':'Methane', 'Unit':'MtCO2eq', '1990':11,'1995':16,'2000':21}]
dt = pd.DataFrame(inp)

dt 
   1990  1995  2000     Region  Scenario     Unit Variable
0     5    10    15      CHINA  Baseline  MtCO2eq  Methane
1     6    11    16      INDIA  Baseline  MtCO2eq  Methane
2     7    12    17  INDONESIA  Baseline  MtCO2eq  Methane
3     8    13    18      KOREA  Baseline  MtCO2eq  Methane
4     9    14    19      JAPAN  Baseline  MtCO2eq  Methane
5    10    15    20   THAILAND  Baseline  MtCO2eq  Methane
6    11    16    21     RUSSIA  Baseline  MtCO2eq  Methane
```

I run this piece of code:

```
dt_test = dt.pivot_table(dt,index=['Scenario','Variable','Unit'],
                           columns=[(df['Region'] == 'CHINA')|
                                   (df['Region'] == 'INDIA')|
                                   (df['Region'] == 'INDONESIA')
                                   |(df['Region'] == 'KOREA')],
                           aggfunc=np.sum)
```

And get this as output:

```
                           1990        1995        2000      
Region                    False True  False True  False True 
Scenario Variable Unit                                       
Baseline Methane  MtCO2eq    46    10    76    15   106    20
```

If someone could help me out with either a way to drop this False column for all the years or another nifty way to get the totals that I want that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (dt_test.xs(True, axis=1, level=1))
                           1990  1995  2000
Scenario Variable Unit                     
Baseline Methane  MtCO2eq    26    46    66
```

But better is filter first by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Region'].isin(['CHINA','INDIA','INDONESIA','KOREA'])]

print (df)
   1990  1995  2000     Region  Scenario     Unit Variable
0     5    10    15      CHINA  Baseline  MtCO2eq  Methane
1     6    11    16      INDIA  Baseline  MtCO2eq  Methane
2     7    12    17  INDONESIA  Baseline  MtCO2eq  Methane
3     8    13    18      KOREA  Baseline  MtCO2eq  Methane
```

And then aggregate `sum` per groups:

```
dt_test = df.groupby(['Scenario','Variable','Unit']).sum()
print (dt_test)
                           1990  1995  2000
Scenario Variable Unit                     
Baseline Methane  MtCO2eq    26    46    66
```